# Limit result amount for each ID to x

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to do something like this in MYSQL, but without making query multiple times (50 times, in my case) through a PHP foreach.

```
foreach($this->map_ids as $key => $val) {
    $this->db->query("SELECT scores.profile_number, scores.score  FROM scores 
                    LEFT JOIN players ON scores.profile_number = players.profile_number
                    WHERE scores.map_id = {'$val'}
                    AND scores.profile_number IN (SELECT profile_number FROM players WHERE banned = 0) LIMIT 10");    
}
```

This is how it looks approximately when I retrieve all scores without LIMIT.

```
profile             score   map_id
76561198026851335   2478    47455
76561198043770492   2480    47455
...                 ...     ...
76561198043899549   1340    47452
76561198048179892   1345    47452
...                 ...     ...
```

I want only 10 entries (scores) from each unique map_id.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is surprisingly difficult to do but I've ended up using **user variables** to do the job, check out the following demo. Obviously my data structure is much simplified but it should be enough to get you going:

**[SQL Fiddle example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!8/32ca9/23)**

Here is the SQL for anyone who may be interested in skipping the demo (hideous, I know)

```
SELECT *
FROM (
      SELECT profile_number, score, map_id
      FROM ( 
        SELECT 
          profile_number, score, map_id, 
          IF( @prev <> map_id, @rownum := 1, @rownum := @rownum+1 ) AS rank, 
          @prev := map_id
        FROM scores 
        JOIN (SELECT @rownum := NULL, @prev := 0) AS r 
        ORDER BY map_id
      ) AS tmp 
      WHERE tmp.rank <= 10 
      ) s
      JOIN players p
        ON s.profile_number = p.profile_number
```

Basically, what is happening is this:
`ORDER BY map_id`
Orders your table by map_id so that all the same ones are together.

Next we assign a rownumber to each row by using the following logic:
`IF( @prev <> map_id, @rownum := 1, @rownum := @rownum+1 )`
If the previous row's map_id is not equal to the current row's ID, set the row number = 1, otherwise increase the rownumber by 1.

Finally, only return the rows who have a rownumber less than or equal to 10
`WHERE tmp.rank <= 10`

Hope that makes it a little clearer for you.

Comment: This works. Thanks. I saw similar answers where user variables are used, but never understood how I can apply it to my problem. This is some black magic for me, understanding this query will take some time. Thank you again. :)

Comment: @ncla Added a bit of an explanation for you, hope that makes it a little easier to understand.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `limit directive.`

```
SELECT * FROM `your_table` LIMIT 0, 10
```

This will display the first 10 results from the database.

```
SELECT * FROM `your_table` LIMIT 5, 5
```

This will show records 6, 7, 8, 9, and 10

Comment: This manual way will not work out as I have over 500 entries.